# Python Django, как сделать пагинацию "показать больше" + Ajax

Tags: python, django

Как реализовать такой функционал ?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вот: https://github.com/shtalinberg/django-el-pagination

Или написать свой view который обрабатывает запросы через `request.is_ajax()`

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/202977)

Comment: @DeKaNszn гитхаб же

Comment: А подробнее про request.is_ajax()

Comment: @Duoxx репозиторий может умереть, переименоваться. то же самое может быть с аккаунтом. Стоит вставить сюда пример кода.